# Can we fail the build for duplicate IntoSet items?

Tags: dagger-2

When we use [@IntoSet](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings#set-multibindings) multibinding and register multiple equal items, then Dagger will use one of the items and silently ignore the others.
Is there a way to configure dagger to check for duplicates and fail the build?
Or is there a workaround forthat?

Comment: Are you sure Dagger is doing the overwriting? By definition sets will ignore duplicates. Can you tell us more about your use case (where multiple identical items should fail), that isn't resolved by tweaking the `equals` implementation or switching to a Map multibinding?

Comment: I didn't really check if the items are overwritten or new ones are ignored.  Anyway the result is the same. When there are duplicates, only one will be used and the others are silently ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure dagger to check for duplicates and fail the build?

No, this is not possible even hypothetically, because the concept of "duplicate items" depends on the *runtime concepts* of `equals` and `hashCode`. Even if the object returned were exactly the same instance or constant, Dagger can only read method signatures at compile time, not code. It can't detect whether separate `@Provides @IntoSet` methods return equal values or literals.

I suspect Dagger itself doesn't check at runtime, either; it leaves the equals-checking and de-duping to the Set implementation. [The Set interface defines its behavior there.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

> Why would you want to register multiple items and then only use a random one of them?

You're right that the behavior should be *deterministic*, not *random* or *arbitrary*, which is part of the reason that you can get a Set (unordered) but not a List (ordered). You're calling the output random, but only because you're distinguishing between the two objects that declare themselves `equal` to one another. If a friend and I split two five-dollar bills, I don't consider the outcome random or nondeterministic, provided that he and I agree the bills are equal to one another.

As far as Java is concerned, you have *two copies of the same object*. This might make sense if you wanted a plugin interface, where ModuleA installs `@Binds @IntoSet Plugin bindFooPlugin(FooPlugin foo);` and ModuleB installs `@Binds @IntoSet Plugin bindFooPlugin(FooPlugin foo);`. Though you could make a good argument for the ideal behavior either way, I would expect FooPlugin to be in the `Set<Plugin>` exactly once, unless its `equals` implementation indicates that Plugin instances are different from one another, in which case I'd expect one per @IntoSet binding.

---

As for workarounds, you could:

- **Tweak the `equals` implementation.** You're seeing this behavior because the two objects are equal. If you don't mean them to be equal, hopefully that's code you can control.
- **Wrap the object for the sake of `equals`.** Guava does this through [`Equivalence.identity().wrap(obj)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#wrap-S-), which requires a number of extra instances but does let you override the inner object's concept of `equals`.
- **Use a Multibindings Map.** Unlike the return values from @IntoSet or @IntoMap, Dagger insists that *map keys are compile-time constants* defined as annotations, which have [a strict definition of equality that can be checked at compile time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). Though you can't use your own custom objects here, Dagger [does break at compile-time for duplicate Map keys](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/internal/codegen/MapMultibindingValidation.java#L145):

  ```
  StringBuilder message =
      new StringBuilder("The same map key is bound more than once for ")
      .append(mapBindingKey);
  ```

  Of course, if you wanted to consume that Map and return a dupe-checked Set of values via [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), you could do that too.